# why this program display differently in async-await?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have a queue to upload images like this:

- the add function push new request to the queue and post it if only itself in the queue.
- the remove function shift the queue then call the callback function, and post next one if exist.

the program should post images and callback one by one.

```js
const img_queue=[] as {posturl:string,data:any,cb:Function,err:Function}[]

function img_add(posturl:string,data:any,cb:Function,err:Function) {
  img_queue.push({posturl,data,cb,err})
  if(img_queue.length==1){
    axios.post(posturl,data)
    .then(result=>{
      img_remove(result,false)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      img_remove(err,true)
    })
  }
}

function img_remove(result:any,err:boolean){
  const one=img_queue.shift();
  (!err)&&one&&one.cb&&one.cb(result);
  err&&one&&one.err&& one.err(result);
  if(img_queue.length>0){
    axios.post(img_queue[0].posturl,img_queue[0].data)
    .then(result=>{
      img_remove(result,false)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      img_remove(err,true)
    })
  }
}

router.post('/uploadImg',(req,res)=>{
  //.......
  img_add(posturl,data,
    (result:any)=>{
      res.json(result)
    },
    (err:any)=>{
      res.status(500).json(err)
    }
  )
})
```

this works fine and meet my goal

however when I change it to async-await way as below:

```js
const img_queue=[]as {posturl:string,data:any,cb:Function,err:Function}[]

async function img_add(posturl:string,data:any,cb:Function,err:Function) {
  img_queue.push({posturl,data,cb,err})
  if(img_queue.length==1){
    try{
      const result= await axios.post(posturl,data)
      await img_remove(result,false)
    }catch(err){
      await img_remove(err,true)
    }
  }
}

async function img_remove(result:any,err:boolean){
  const one=img_queue.shift();
  (!err)&&one&&one.cb&&one.cb(result);
  err&&one&&one.err&&one.err(result);
  if(img_queue.length>0){
    try{
      const result=await axios.post(img_queue[0].posturl,img_queue[0].data)
      await img_remove(result,false)
    }catch(err){
      await img_remove(err,true)
    }
  }
}

router.post('/uploadImg',async(req,res)=>{
 //.....
  await img_add(posturl,data,
    (result:any)=>{
      res.json(result)
    },
    (err:any)=>{
      res.status(500).json(err)
    }
  )
})
```

it works differently

it seems only the first callback was executed

why does this happen?
is any step i made it wrong?

Comment: In your first snippet, neither `img_add` nor `img_remove` do return promises, and most importantly you didn't `await` the `img_remove(…)` calls.

Comment: But the first snippet works properly. Problem happens in the second

Comment: That's what I'm saying.

Comment: I finally understand what you mean:there is no need to await a non-promise.thanks!